# Cannot use redux data in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am making a react-redux site.

I am accessing data called from an api via redux.

I understand that ComponentDidMount will not wait for this data to be called so I was wondering on a better way to split this data within a parent component into arrays for children components (or if this method is a bad choice).

This is the component and will hopefully shed some light on what is going on.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPosts, fetchItins } from "../../../actions/postActions";
import TravelAlerts from "./TravelAlerts//travelAlert";
import IntelligenceAlerts from "./IntelligenceAlerts/IntelligenceAlert";
import AllAlerts from "./AllAlerts/AllAlerts";

class Alerts extends Component {
  state = {
    showAllAlerts: true,
    showAllIntelligenceAlerts: false,
    showAllTravellers: false,
    currentPage: 1,
    alertsPerPage: 20,
    travelAlerts: [],
    intelligenceAlerts: [],
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
    console.log(this.props.posts);
 

    for (var key in this.props.posts) {
      if (this.props.posts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key === "travelAlerts") {
          alert("travel ALerts Hit");
        } else if (key === "intelligenceAlerts") {
          alert("intelligenceAlertsHIts");
        } else {
        }
        console.log(key + " -> " + this.props.posts[key]);
      }
    }
  }

  //navigation helper
  DisableAlerts() {
    this.setState({
      showAllAlerts: false,
      showAllIntelligenceAlerts: false,
      showAllTravellers: false,
    });
  }

  //pagination change page
  handleClick(number) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: number,
    });
  }
  ToogleAlertType(name) {
    this.DisableAlerts();

    if (name === "All") {
      this.setState({ showAllAlerts: true });
    } else if (name === "Intelligence") {
      this.setState({ showAllIntelligenceAlerts: true });
    } else if (name === "Travellers") {
      this.setState({ showAllTravellers: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ showAllAlerts: true });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          style={{ width: "30%" }}
          onClick={() => this.ToogleAlertType("ALL")}
        >
          ALL{" "}
        </button>
        <button
          style={{ width: "30%" }}
          onClick={() => this.ToogleAlertType("Intelligence")}
        >
          Intelligence{" "}
        </button>
        <button
          style={{ width: "30%" }}
          onClick={() => this.ToogleAlertType("Travellers")}
        >
          Travellers
        </button>
        <br />
        <hr />

        <div>
          {this.state.showAllAlerts ? (
            <>{/* <AllAlerts alerts={this.props.posts} /> */}</>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </div>

        <>
          {this.state.showAllTravellers ? (
            <>
              <></>
              {/* <TravelAlerts alerts={this.props.posts} /> */}
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </>
        <>
          {this.state.showAllIntelligenceAlerts ? (
            <>{/* <IntelligenceAlerts alerts ={this.props.posts}/> */}</>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Alerts.propTypes = {
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  // newPost: PropTypes.object
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: state.posts.items,
  // newPost: state.posts.item
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Alerts);
```

The component is mapped to redux and is working fine however the data being retrieved is within an object and I would like this to be two separate arrays which I could then pass down to the child components etc.

This is what I am currently trying to do in the component did mount just to see if it can find the keys.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
    console.log(this.props.posts);


    for (var key in this.props.posts) {
      if (this.props.posts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key === "travelAlerts") {
          alert("travel ALerts Hit");
        } else if (key === "intelligenceAlerts") {
          alert("intelligenceAlertsHIts");
        } else {
        }
        console.log(key + " -> " + this.props.posts[key]);
      }
    }
  }
```

However the data does not show when mounted(works in render method but I feel that is not a good place to put it).

Is this a good direction to head in or should I have split these into two separate arrays before they have even reached the component? If so should this be done so in the reducer or in the actions?

Really appreciate any help as I am new to redux.

EDIT
This is my fetch posts

```
export const fetchPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
  fetch(
    "the url im using"
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((posts) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_POSTS,
        payload: posts,
      })
    );
};
```

My reducer

```
import { FETCH_POSTS, NEW_POST, FETCH_ITINS } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  items: {},
  item: {},
  itins: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload,
      };
    case NEW_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        item: action.payload,
      };
    case FETCH_ITINS:
      return {
        ...state,
        itins: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what is your fetchPosts is doing

Comment: Updated  the question :)

Comment: If calling `this.props.fetchPosts();` will change `this.props.posts`, React will call `componentDidUpdate(...)` because the props changed. Also, `fetch()` is async, but even if it weren't, React wouldn't call `componentDidMount` again.

Comment: Chris G. I put this into a component did update and it worked. If you would like to put a answer I will mark it as the answer otherwise I will post what I have as answer.